# PALM Pre Emulator

Tags: webos, palm-pre

Has an emulator been created for the PALM Pre phone yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

The SDK has been released to the general public. More information [here](http://developer.palm.com/).

---

**Original Answer**

From http://developer.palm.com/

> Only a select few partners received
> the initial release of the Mojo SDK.
> Now we’re expanding access to it,
> which could mean access for you. If
> you’re interested in participating,
> complete the application at the link
> below. Not everyone will receive the
> Mojo SDK right away. But when you do,
> you’ll see how easy it is to develop
> for the Palm webOS™ platform.
>
> (Source: [Engadget: Palm's Mojo SDK for webOS in pictures](http://www.engadgetmobile.com/2009/01/13/palms-mojo-sdk-for-webos-in-pictures/))

Comment: Thanks.  I applied for the SDK tonight.  Hopefully I get accepted.

Comment: Palm released the SDK today, go get it!

Answer (score 1):

... wait for the Mojo SDK, they are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Palm released the SDK to everyone today. Go get it!

Answer (score 1):

The emulator is now available to the public as the webOS developer program has been opened up to wide participation.  You can download it along with the SDK from http://developer.palm.com/